# How to properly call a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a Python (and programming in general) newbie and I'm trying to make a text-based, endless rpg with random rooms/encounters based on a list. This code is (of course) not completed yet, It's just for testing. Note that I imported Enemies from another .py file:

```
import Enemies
import random    


class Room:
# template definition to define all rooms
    def __init__(self, intro):
        self.intro = intro


class VsRoom(Room):
# room with an enemy
    def __init__(self, enemy):
        self.enemy = random.choice(Enemy_List)
        super().__init__(intro = "There's an enemy here!")


class NullRoom(Room):
# empty, boring room
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intro = "Nothing Interesting here.")


Rooms = [VsRoom, NullRoom]  # All future room "types" will go here


def print_room():
# Tells the player which kind of room they are
    print("You enter the next room...")
    Gen_Room = random.choice(Rooms)
    print(Gen_Room.intro)
```

I wanted print room() to print "You enter on the next room...", randomly pick a room from the list, and print its intro, but when I try to run it I get this:

```
You enter the next room...
[...]
 print(Gen_Room.intro)
AttributeError: type object 'NullRoom' has no attribute 'intro'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm trying to learn how classes work and any help would be great for me. I tried to follow PEP8 as much as I could, and I also tried to find similar questions, without success.

Comment: what is the value of `Enemy_List` and for which you use enemy in `def _init__(self, enemy):`

Comment: `Enemy_List` is a list that comes from another .py file called `Enemies`. The existence of enemy in `def _init__(self, enemy):` wasn't necessary, as stated below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I observe you have a list of where you choose the enemies, so you do not need to enter that parameter:

```
class VsRoom(Room):
# room with an enemy
    def __init__(self):
        self.enemy = random.choice(Enemy_List)
        super().__init__(intro = "There's an enemy here!")
```

To create an instance you must do it as follows:

```
{class name}()
```

So you must change:

```
Gen_Room = random.choice(Rooms)
```

To:

```
Gen_Room = random.choice(Rooms)()
```

**Complete code:**

```
import Enemies
import random    

class Room:
# template definition to define all rooms
    def __init__(self, intro):
        self.intro = intro


class VsRoom(Room):
# room with an enemy
    def __init__(self):
        self.enemy = random.choice(Enemy_List)
        super().__init__(intro = "There's an enemy here!")


class NullRoom(Room):
# empty, boring room
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intro = "Nothing Interesting here.")


Rooms = [VsRoom, NullRoom]  # All future room "types" will go here


def print_room():
# Tells the player which kind of room they are
    print("You enter the next room...")
    Gen_Room = random.choice(Rooms)()
    print(Gen_Room.intro)
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working now. I also forgot to type `Enemies.Enemy_List` instead of `Enemy_List`.